# Schema table in Laravel add column dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a dynamic add product form in which I access field and category related to type .

1. fields table have fieldname and id
2. type table have title.
   field and type have mane to many relation in model
3. category table have category name and type id
4. product table have category id and attributes related to product.

I add product on the basis of type id if type_id is 1 then type_id 1 related fields and category show on add product form.

Now problem is that when first time  URL load field list of type_id show but when second time, check only first field if product table have that field then other field skipped.

```
public function create($id){
    $type = Type::find($id);
    $category = Category::all();
    foreach ($type->field as $key => $value) {
        if ( Schema::hasColumn('products', "{$value->fieldname}") ) {
            return view('products.create', compact('type', 'category'));
        } else {
            if( ! Schema::hasColumn('products', "{$value->fieldname}") ) {
                foreach ($type->field as $key => $value) {
                    Schema::table('products', function ($table) use ($value) {
                        $table->string("{$value->fieldname}")->nullable()-> after('category_id');
                    });
                }

                return view('products.create', compact('type', 'category'));
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the best practice to dynamically add columns like that to your table. If you want, however, you could use a separate table to hold meta information so that you can easily add/remove "columns" as needed.

For example, you could set your meta table up like this:

```
create table `products_meta` (
    products_id int(11),
    column_name varchar(255),
    value varchar(255),
)
```

Then in your products model, add functionality to get, insert, check if exists, etc.

```
public function getMeta($column) {
    $meta =  DB::table('products_meta')
        ->select('column_name', 'value')
        ->where('products_id', '=', $this->id)
        ->where('column_name', '=', $column)
        ->get();

    if (!$meta->isEmpty()) {
        return $meta;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public function addMeta($column, $value) {
    DB::table('products_meta')->insert(
       [
        'products_id' => $this->id,
        'column_name' => $column, 
        'value' => $value,
       ]
    );
}
```